# Does self-assignment do anything during variable definition?

Tags: c, variable-assignment

I have some code before me like this:

```
uint16_t a = a = (uint16_t) (bPtr);
```

Does this do anything special that I'm not aware of?  Or is it equivalent to this:

```
uint16_t a = (uint16_t) (bPtr);
```

I'm guessing it's just a typo from combining

```
uint16_t a;
a = (uint16_t) (bPtr);
```

Comment: Looks to me like a "do-nothing" expression, and code-smell that should be cleaned up.

Comment: It is the same and it does nothing special

Comment: Typo... just fix it

Comment: Semantically it should be the same as assigning a single time. What code gets generated depends on the compiler - the compiler is free to issue assignment 1 or 2 times (or not at all if it finds the whole thing can be optimized away).

Comment: This is UB in C++ because you access the variable before its lifetime starts. I'm unsure about C, but I would avoid it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: There is no reason to think the object is accessed before its lifetime starts because the assignment’s side effect of updating the stored value is not sequenced before the initialization of the object. It is sequenced before evaluation of the next full expression starts. Further, for an object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without `static`, its lifetime starts at entry into the block with which it is associated, per C 2018 6.2.4 6. So it already exists by the time program execution reaches the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it does the same. No difference.

But if the variable is declared as `volatile` it will write it twice. I was using on the hardware where (because of the silicon bug) one of the hardware registers had to be written twice

```
void writeREG(unsigned addr, uint32_t val)
{
    *(volatile uint32_t *)addr = *(volatile uint32_t *)addr = val;
}
```

and the code:

```
writeREG:
        str     r1, [r0]
        str     r1, [r0]
        bx      lr
```

Comment: If it needs to be assigned twice, I think it should be accompanied by a big flashing comment saying why :)

Answer (score 4):

The intermixing of initialization and evaluation of expressions in initializers is not well defined by the C standard, particularly in regard to side effects in those initializers. However, `uint16_t a = a = (uint16_t) (bPtr);` is best regarded as undefined behavior because it violates C 2018 6.5 2:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined…

In `uint16_t a = a = (uint16_t) (bPtr);`, the assignment has the side effect of updating the scalar object `a`. The initialization is not well defined in regard to whether it behaves like an assignment that occurs when the object is created. In the absence of such specification by the C standard, we should regard it as unsequenced relative to the assignment’s side effect, and therefore 6.5 2 renders the behavior of the program not defined by the C standard.

In contrast, `uint16_t a = (uint16_t) (bPtr);` is fully defined (as long as `bPtr` has been assigned a proper value).

The former code should never be used and should be corrected to the latter.